# Asymptotic volume of intersection of n-ball and a cube

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, asymptotics

Let $B$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $c\in(0,1)$ be a constant. I'm trying to find the asymptotics for the volume of the intersection $[\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}},1]^n\cap B$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Is there nice asymptotic formula for this volume?

Comment: Depends on the precision you want. For the crude asymptotic just think Gaussian.

Comment: In other words, it is $(2\pi)^{n/2}n^{-(n+1)/2}Q(c)^n$ where $Q(c)=\min_{t>0}[\Phi(ct)\frac 1t e^{t^2/2}]$ and $\Phi(z)=P(\xi>z)$ ($\xi$ is the standard 1D normal r.v.) is the Gaussian tail function. That is correct up to a constant factor depending on $c\in(0,1)$ but not on $n$.